# How to list only the aliases defined by the user?

Tags: linux, zsh, command, alias, oh-my-zsh

I'm using the ZSH and defined some aliases (stored in multiple fines, that are loaded in the `~/.zshrc`). That is working fine. Executing the command `alias` allows to list all available aliases.

Now I'd like to have a possibility to list only the custom aliases aliases, meaning: only the aliases, defined by the current user. How can I do that?

Comment: Note that `zsh` only defines two aliases by itself (`run-help` and `which-command`), the rest is done by the user by invoking the `alias` builtin or assigning to `${,g,s}aliases` variables, even if it's via sourcing third party code like oh-my-zsh.

Answer (score 1):

You could record the list of aliases before you start defining any of your own in your `~/.zshrc` (or wherever you define your *own* aliases):

```
aliases_before=()
printf -v aliases_before '%s=%s' "${(kv@)aliases}"
```

And then compare that with the current list.

```
aliases_now=()
printf -v aliases_now '%s=%s' "${(kv@)aliases}"
print -rC1 'Now and not before:' ${aliases_now:|aliases_before}
```

That's using the `$aliases` special associative array that exposes the list  of *normal* aliases and their definition.  See `$galiases` and `$saliases` for the global and suffix aliases.

Note that if you redefine an alias the exact same way it was defined before, it won't show up in  that list.

---

Another approach is to use a `my-alias` function to define your aliases that records them in an associative array of its own

```
typeset -A my_aliases
my-alias() {
  local alias
  for alias do
    my_aliases[${alias%%=*}]=${alias#*=}
  done
  alias "$@"
}
```

Then: `typeset my_aliases` to see your aliases.

---

Note that aliases are more of a csh feature.  Bourne-like shells have functions which are far superior (though can't be used for everything aliases are used for).

If you defined your aliases as functions instead,  like `la() ls -la "$@"` instead of `alias ls='ls -la'`, then you'd be able to query the list of functions that are defined in a given file.

For instance,

```
print -rC1 -- ${(k)functions_source[(Re)$HOME/.zshrc]}
```

Would list the functions defined in `~/.zshrc`, and

```
whence -f --  ${(k)functions_source[(Re)$HOME/.zshrc]}
```

Would also show their definition.